# R Programming: Logical test of Previous/preceding/successive Column

Tags: r, matrix, indexing, comparison

I have a matrix called 'ft', a result of some logical tests. 
Here is the example, a matrix of [10,5]. 
In real work it will be thousands of row, more column and around hundreds of matrix.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [3,]    0    1    1    1    1
 [4,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [5,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [6,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [7,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [8,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [9,]    1    1    1    1    1
[10,]    1    0    1    1    1
```

I need to do a logical test of the value from previous column. If the value from previous column is zero, then the rest of the column will be zero.
For example the value of vector `[3,1]` is zero, hence the rest of the column in row `[3,]`  will be zero. Likewise, the element in `[10,2]` is zero, thus the row `[10,3:5]` will be zero
So the result in a new matrix will be like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [5,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [6,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [7,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [8,]    1    1    1    1    1
 [9,]    1    1    1    1    1
[10,]    1    0    0    0    0
```

I am completely new in R,  I have tried several alternative like the following:

```
ctes=cbind(ftes[,1], (ftes[,2:t]==1 & ctes[,-1]==1))
```

But it is completely wrong. 
How to do this efficiently with vectorized method instead of loop test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think base R offers a vectorized way to solve this, but you could try the `matrixStats` package if efficiency is important

```
matrixStats::rowCummins(ft)
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#  [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
#  [2,]    1    1    1    1    1
#  [3,]    0    0    0    0    0
#  [4,]    1    1    1    1    1
#  [5,]    1    1    1    1    1
#  [6,]    1    1    1    1    1
#  [7,]    1    1    1    1    1
#  [8,]    1    1    1    1    1
#  [9,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [10,]    1    0    0    0    0
```

A benchmark for a 200MB size matrix

```
set.seed(123)
Bigft <- matrix(sample(0:1, 5e7, replace = TRUE), ncol = 100)
system.time(matrixStats::rowCummins(Bigft))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.08    0.01    0.10
```

Comment: Nice function that you have found there (+1). It may however be worth pointing out that this solution requires a matrix with only 1 and 0 values. Although this condition seems to be fulfilled in the case described by the OP it is not explicitly stated.

Comment: @RHertel, yeah I realize that, but the user said that matrix is a result of some "*logical tests*"- so I guess it should be always a binary matrix.

Comment: @DavidArenburg wow! that's powerful. Thanks a lot for your reply, it works and sufficient for my case above. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a simpler way, but this should work:

```
zeros <- which(ft==0,arr.ind=TRUE)
sapply(1:nrow(zeros), function(x) ft[zeros[x,1], zeros[x,2]:ncol(ft)] <<- 0)
#> ft
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [2,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [5,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [6,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [7,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [8,]    1    1    1    1    1
# [9,]    1    1    1    1    1
#[10,]    1    0    0    0    0
```

This is not vectorized, but the loop extends only over the rows containing a zero, and not the entire matrix. Depending on the density of the matrix, this may or may not make a huge difference.

**data**

```
ft <- structure(c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
      1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(10L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, NULL))
```

Comment: Or with `apply` and `cummin` i.e. `t(apply(ft, 1, function(x) cummin(x)))`

Comment: @Rhetel thanks for the answer, but i need to go with the one from david for the moment.